# Metadata Tags not available in search refinement panel

Tags: search, migration, managed-metadata

We migrated a SharePoint 2007 solution to 2010 a while back. We also added a 'managed metadata application' to our new 2010 solution. Since then users have added a lot of terms to the content. This content is now searchable but somehow we don't get any terms in search refinement panel. There is nothing in the logs indicating an error.

<strike>Could it be because the migrated sites are having a different Locale (regional settings) that whats used in 'managed metadata application' (i.e. english) ? Or is it something else ?</strike>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damn, it was a stupid mistake by me. I had custom code which set some metadata programatically, using the following code

```
item[tagsFieldName] = tagsValues;
```

instead of the standard way i.e.

```
tagsField.SetFieldValue(item, tagsValues);
```

I have changed the code and everything works perfectly now

Comment: I have exact same issue where I added some properties in the search option. Howerver 2 of these properties are set to term set. Is there certain way i need to code in order to show term sets for user to pick from.   <Properties>
<Property Name="CustomerAccounts" ManagedName="CustomerAccounts" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:CustomerAccounts"/>
</Properties>

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value for "MetadataThreshold" in the Filter Category Definition XML? You can change it to 0 (zero) for test purposes.

Here is a link that explains how the MetadataThreshold works: http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/refinement-panel-metadatathreshold-configuration/

Comment: I tried setting MetadataThreshold="0" but it didn't work

Comment: Does the refinement panel work with other filters, like site or autor?

Comment: @Anita, yes other filters were there.

Answer (score 0):

I have read http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/08/ensuring-refinements-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-2010/ on the topic and it might help some of you, too.

Comment: Hi Mark, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Although your answer may answer the question, links to blog posts often break, where as we won't be going anywhere for a long while. It's always a good idea to extract the useful parts for research if not all of it incase that happens (If it's not too long!) Please read the [FAQ][1] for more information [1]:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq